# Mac OS X Windows and Ubuntu On Mac Book Pro Mid 2015

Tags: dual-boot, bootloader, macbook

I have a Mac Book Pro mid 2015 and I was using it with Windows 10 installed with Bootcamp. I have tried to install Ubuntu 16.04. I have resized my Mac partition to open space for Ubuntu and instaled it by following below two tutorials:

- [Installing Ubuntu 15.10 - Wily Werewolf on a Macbook Pro 12-1 (2015)](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookPro12-1/Wily)
- [How To Install Linux On A MacBook Pro Retina](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/install-linux-macbook-pro/)

Wile selecting partitions to install i have selected `/dev/sda` for installing boot loader. When installation complate i have installed `efibootmgr` as suggested. But when i reboot computer it tried to boot with Windows but my boot sector was broken. I have tried to install again but this time i have selected `/dev/sda1` for boot loader installation. After complating installation and reboot i am now able to see GRUB menu and select Ubuntu or Windows. But Windows's boot sector still is broken and there is no option to select Mac OS X. I am only able to boot with Mac OS X by pressing `alt` key while computer starts.

My question is how can i add option for Mac OS X to GRUB and how can i fix my Windows bootloader?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your best option is to install rEFInd

https://sourceforge.net/projects/refind/

That way you will be able to access all of your Oses.

Here is a video of how to install it.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-IuZj9Wf9dI

Comment: I have installed but didn't work.

Comment: How did you do it?

Comment: I have just manage to install it  and open Ubuntu :)

Comment: But my Windows boot sector is still broken.

Comment: Great, can you see your mac partition?

Comment: Yes i am able to open Mac OS X.